# JavaScript Regex question

Tags: javascript

All,

I have following function to check for invalid symbols entered in a text box and return true or false. How can I modify this function to also check for occurrences like http:// and https:// and ftp:// return false if encountered ?

```
function checkURL(textboxval) {
   return ! (/[<>()#'"]|""/.test(textboxval));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: do you wish to catch any protocol specifier or just those in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function checkURL(textboxval) {
   return ! (/[<>()#'"]|""|(https?|ftp)\:\/\//.test(textboxval));
}
```

Comment: How to check for case insensitive?

Answer (score 1):

You want it to return false if it encounters a protocol?

```
function checkURL(textboxval) {
    return ! (/[<>()#'"]|""|(f|ht)tp(s)?:\/\//.test(textboxval));
}
```

This is a useful tool for figuring these things out also: [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: I like the fact that `(f|ht)tp(s)?` the same length, but much harder to read and less efficient than `(https?|ftp)`… ;-) If you take non-capturing groups it even gets *longer* than the straight-forward variant.

Comment: Thanks.. This works fine.. It should return false even if the protocol is entered in CAPS.. But it returns true...

Comment: If you want it to be case-insensitive, end the regex with /i.

Comment: Tomalak, you're correct. I started with just `http` and then was mucking around in the tester and forgot to clean it up before posting here.